# How to reduce the memory used by a site with many domain aliases

Tags: 7, caching

I have a Drupal 7 site which runs on a Centos 6 x64 server with 4GB RAM, Apache, Memcache and Opcache.

The drupal site has a base domain 'example.com' and 2000 domain aliases (parked domains) which each point to its own landing page in the same website (sales pages).

The .htaccess contains one rewrite rules that includes the domain name as variable (without the dot) in the url. In that way the parked domains each show their own node. The rule is as follows:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)\.(\w+)
  RewriteRule ^/?$ ?q=landingpage/%1%2 [L,QSA]
```

- With the 2000 aliases, the memory is insufficient and the server
  becomes unresponsive.
- Without aliases, the website uses approx. 500MB RAM.
- The maximum number of aliases appears to be around 500, with the
  server still functioning normally.

I think (but I'm not sure) that Memcache stores all aliases as complete separate websites, while it should only cache the codebase once.

I would like to optimize the memory usage with regard to the domain aliases, so that max 4GB RAM can be used. As a last resort, I could exclude the domain aliases from Memcache, if that is possible. (I have not found documentation that confirms this.)

Comment: Opcache stores compiled php files, which it identifies by looking at files on the local filesystem. Opcache is not aware of where the request came from. Since you mention aliases I assume there is a shared Drupal root? In that case Opcache is not your bad guy. (If you would have 2000 Drupal folders, Opcache would have a hard time, but still has a configured max memory usage to which it holds (and so does memcache))

Comment: Yes you are right, it's not Opcache we have to look at here. Thats one step, And yes, its a shared Drupal root.

Comment: Where does it become unresponsive? Web server? PHP? Drupal? What do you mean by "normal amount of RAM"? E.g. normal for me is 16GB+, so your current hardware is massively sub-normal in my experience. Cache bins on a multisite need to be separate if they use different databases (with a separate prefix for each defined in settings.php), or can be shared if using the same data for all. How is yours set up? I wouldn't hold out for an answer until you can provide more background information, there are potentially a lot of other areas you need to investigate before assuming this a Drupal issue

Comment: The server RAM and CPU usage both become close to 100%. The webserver becomes unresponsive since this drupal site with the aliases makes all other websites on the server unresponsive.

Comment: That isn't new information though - you need to debug this yourself, it can't be done by anyone without access to the site and server. Find out where the bottleneck is, whether it's an Apache problem (too many vhosts?), PHP problem (extensions? xdebug installed? opcache disabled to confirm?) or Drupal (debug the application itself, put breakpoints or simply die in index.php to see if the slowdown happens before or after Drupal gets involved, carry on through other parts of the system until you isolate the culprit).

Comment: This Drupal site is just a single D7 site with one database and one codebase. Sorry I said 'shared' codebase but actually there is only one website. All the parked domains point to the Drupal homepage and I have set up htaccess to rewrite the requests of all domains except from the base domain, to landingpages of the same drupal site.

Comment: 2000 rewrites in .htaccess? That'll be at least part of the problem. I know first-hand from a recently inherited mess that 1200+ rules puts seconds on to a single page load on a production Apache server (one with more resources than the spec you mentioned)

Comment: Clive, it is actually one rewrite in htaccess. The url is rewritten to include the actual domain name as variable (each pointing to an existing node. About the debugging: you are right, I will do more testing in that way.

Comment: There you go, you pretty much just eliminated Apache :) Just think in those sort of terms and you'll find the bottleneck pretty quickly. Fixing it might be more difficult of course but at least you'll know, and adding what you find into the question will massively increase the chance of someone being able to give advice. I'd even put the rewrite rule in there to be honest, the more users can understand the end-to-end process the better

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly/stupid comment, but do you have an idea if it would yes or no help to transform this site in a multi site with 4 sites, each of them with 500 aliases? 4*500=2000 ... It seems to me that you'd reduce your issue to 25% , simply by using a standard Drupal technique. I'm not a fan of multi sites (single point of failure, etc), but this case might be an exception for it.